# Is there any way for backing up our files using SQL server?

Tags: sql-server

I have used SQL Server for backing up database files through defining Job or Maintenance Plane over and over.

I know how it works when it's just about database files, I was wondering if there is any trick to make SQL Server to create a scheduled backup for my asp codes, I mean I'm looking for a trick to make SQL Server handle backing up files in given path at specific time, maybe using some kind of job or something like that.

Comment: If you insist on using the SQL Agent Scheduler, you could make it run a PowerShell script to collect your files and stuff them away. The same could be achieved simply using Windows Task Scheduler. Depending on the user running your SQL Agent Service (default local user), you may run into issues when you need to access network shares.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use SQL Agent jobs to run operating system tasks, such as file backup.

Have a look at implementing jobs [topic](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssms/agent/implement-jobs)